LWC console logs is not showing component names in the chrome console
So generally when i debug/ i use console or to get break points in use the component name on the right highlighted in red. Simple click on it navigates to the js code and debug it accordingly.
but right now that is not happening, the component name is not showing up, it just gives some auraprod or something which does not make sense. how do i get it back any ideas?


Do you have LWS enabled?

Yes, it was found out it should be disabled if I need it that way!! Took me long time googling to figure out!

If you want to debug your lightning component. I would prefer to go to "Debug Mode" under Lightning Component.

And enabled debug for your user. Then you should be able to put debugger points on your custom lightning components.
I would prefer not to disable "LWS" ,just because your component name is not appearing, as it can have other issues.

Thanks !it helped

This is because LWS might be enabled in your org's session settings. You can disable this by navigating to the
Quick Find --> Session Settings --> Unchecking the 'Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components and Aura components'

Note: You can enable the LWS once you are done with your debugging

Thanks it helped!

Updated the answer with the note
